# Prevent clang format putting a space between return and an initialiser list

Tags: c++, clang-format

I'm creating a clang-format file for an existing codebase. Is there a way to prevent clang-format from formatting:

```cpp
std::string foo()
{
    return{};
}
```

To have a space between the return and the braces:

```cpp
std::string foo()
{
    return {};
}
```

I've tried setting `SpaceBeforeCpp11BracedList` to `false` but that doesn't seem to apply here.

Comment: I doubt it. But I'm also on clang-format's side on this one.

Comment: @sweenish me too, but its an existing code base and I'm trying to match the used style

Comment: I feel that. I'm on the committee working to roll out clang-format for our company. There are going to be changes to our style. At least it will be a consistent change across the entire codebase, and people can still write it that way if it's muscle memory. I've found there are only a handful of ways to write C++ that clang-format will mangle into something that doesn't compile. Mostly to do with macros.